# Ubuntu 20.04 Freeze after utilizing NVIDIA GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04

As the title already explains, my Ubuntu 20.04 crashes (often, not always) when utilizing the GPU. Here's my `nvidia-smi` output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.100      Driver Version: 440.100      CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     73MiB /  4042MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1320      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            36MiB |
|    0      2319      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            36MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When, for example running tensorflow models, I can utilize the GPU (100%) approx. 5 secs before my system (Dell XPS 15 9560) freezes. The selected prime profile is "NVIDIA On-Demand". (I also dont know how to run for example tux kart on my gpu or any other application like valley benchmark (all using igpu), but tensorflow works for whatever reason (maybe cuda?))

So to summarize:

Setup: Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell XPS 9560 with Mobile GTX 1050
Probem: Ubuntu 20.04 freezing after short usage of GPU

(If you need any logs or something like that, lmk I dont have a clue where they are)

Comment: EDIT: This only happens in the mode mentioned above (On-Demand), the other mode (Performance Mode) works without problems